# Open connection between app and server

Tags: java, android, objective-c, ios

I want to create connection between app (in mobile device) and server.

Also it would be great to send some info at a time to app and that server would know if that info reached app.

Has anyone tried this?

I would appreciate for any information.

Comment: Do you need help with Android or iOS?

Comment: I would implement both in same way. So it isn't important. I hope that Android or iOS developers had done something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried that for iOS, actually it was an app that required synchronising several devices across a network.

To achieve what you want you need to use sockets. There are two kinds of sockets: [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol). These are protocols that run on the protocol OSI layer. Read more about TCP/IP stack [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP).

When you read all this you will understand why you need to use sockets, and specifically TCP sockets, which are the ones than can ensure delivery.

For iOS, I recommend using [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), a third party library that substantially leverages the hassle of using sockets at a low level.
For Android I can't tell you right away, but I've used java.net.socket in the past with success, but I'm sure a google search will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For Android:

You can use [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html). [More here.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)
To send info from server to device use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)

Good luck!